# How to restart bluetooth service when my server service restarts in systemd

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, systemd

I am using systemd services on an embedded system. I have a web service that needs to restart bluetooth everytime it restarts. How do I write the unit file for this. Also the service I have is put into systemd/user and not systemd/system.
I tried using PartOf=bluetooth.service but that didn't work.

```
[Unit]

# Human readable name of the unit
Description=Python User Service
#Link it to bluetooth
After=bluetooth.service
Requires=bluetooth.service
PartOf=bluetooth.service

[Service]

# Command to execute when the service is started
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/root/MyServ.py

# Disable Python's buffering of STDOUT and STDERR, so that output from the
# service shows up immediately in systemd's logs
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Automatically restart the service if it crashes
Restart=on-failure

# Our service will notify systemd once it is up and running
#Type=notify
Type=simple

# Use a dedicated user to run our service
User=root

[Install]

# Tell systemd to automatically start this service when the system boots
# (assuming the service is enabled)
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: `# Tell systemd to automatically start this service when the system boots
# (assuming the service is enabled)
WantedBy=default.target` but better use `WantedBy=multi-user.target` and after that `systemd enable` the service.

Comment: I changed default.target to 'multi-user.target' and started seeing "bluetooth.service not found". I then changed that to just 'bluetooth'. It restarts my service but it doesn't restart bluetooth as 'systemctl status bluetooth' shows that its been running for over an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `[Unit]` section you can reload services

> PropagatesReloadTo=, ReloadPropagatedFrom=
>
> A space-separated list of one or more units where reload requests on this unit will be propagated to, or reload requests on the
>   other unit will be propagated to this unit, respectively. Issuing a
>   reload request on a unit
>          will automatically also enqueue a reload request on all units that the reload request shall be propagated to via these two settings.

It sends bluetoothd command to reload via dbus. Not kill daemon, just reread configuration.

---

Or on `[Service]` section

```
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

---

Or use `override.conf` on bluetooth.service

```
systemctl edit bluetooth.service
```

And here put

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=MyServ.service
```